# Include indices in Pandas groupby results

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

With Pandas groupby, I can do things like this:

```python
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "A": ["foo", "bar", "bar", "foo", "bar"],
...         "B": ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
...     }
... )
>>> print(df)
     A      B
0  foo    one
1  bar    two
2  bar  three
3  foo   four
4  bar   five
>>> print(df.groupby('A')['B'].unique())
A
bar    [two, three, five]
foo           [one, four]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

What I am looking for is output that produces a list of indices instead of a list of column B:

```python
A
bar    [1, 2, 4]
foo    [0, 3]
```

However, groupby('A').index.unique() doesn't work. What syntax would provide me the output I'm after? I'd be more than happy to do this in some other way than with groupby, although I do need to group by two columns in my real application.

Comment: Do you want the unique indices of the indices of the unique values in B? (This is not the same!)

Comment: Good point! In my case, though, they are both unique because it's a pseudonymization table. So I guess either would work in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to have a label in `groupby`, you can use a grouping object.

This enables things like:

```py
df.index.to_series().groupby(df['A']).unique()
```

output:

```
A
bar    [1, 2, 4]
foo       [0, 3]
dtype: object
```

###### getting the indices of the unique B values:

```py
df[~df[['A', 'B']].duplicated()].index.to_series().groupby(df['A']).unique()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`Groupby.Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html)

```
In [530]: df.reset_index().groupby('A')['index'].unique()
Out[530]: 
A
bar    [1, 2, 4]
foo       [0, 3]
Name: index, dtype: object
```

**OR:**

```
In [533]: df.reset_index().groupby('A')['index'].agg(list)
Out[533]: 
A
bar    [1, 2, 4]
foo       [0, 3]
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the agg function. unique() felt a bit like cheating. Will explore agg() a bit more!

Answer (score 2):

If you want indices of unique values in 'B', as opposed to unique indices, then you can do

```
df.reset_index().groupby('A').apply(lambda g: g.drop_duplicates(['B'])['index'].tolist())
```

it is different from @Mayank and @mozway answers when applied to a slightly modified example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["foo", "bar", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"],
        "B": ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "one"],
    }
)
```

My answer would return

```
A
bar    [1, 2, 4]
foo       [0, 3]
dtype: object
```

whereas @Mayank and @mozway would return

```
A
bar    [1, 2, 4]
foo    [0, 3, 5]
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Comment: that was my question to OP as comment ;) I also have updated my answer with a solution (you don't need apply!)

Answer (score 0):

One intuitive way is to add a line for defining a new column as index, and you can keep using the same code as you wrote.

```
df['index'] = df.index
df.groupby('A')['index'].unique()
```

Result:

[image]